# Powershell setting up a new user with a specific attribute

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

I have a script that creates new users that can be used for different operations.

```
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
  [string]$GivenName, #=givenName

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2)]
  [string]$Name, # =sn

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=9)]
  [string]$ADuser, 

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=4)]
  [string]$Description, #=title


[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=4)]
  [string]$AdministrationUser,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=4)]
  [string]$SamAccManager
)
```

after these parameters I have a new-user -name and so on, But I want to user the last Parameter SamAccManager to be added to the adminDisplayName, so I can search who is in charge of that AD user as there will be users that have no logon rights, will be used only for test purposes.

```
new-aduser -name $DisplayName -DisplayName $DisplayName -Description $Description -GivenName $GivenName -Surname $Name -SamAccountName $usr -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName -Path $OU_AD
```

How Can I integrate to add that info into that specific adminDisplayName field? for example, I want to add in the last section code -admindisplayname $samaccmanager , but I can not do that as it is an invalid parameter. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I noticed is that you add duplicate values for `Position` to the parameters. Also, there is a parameter you do not seem to use: `$AdministrationUser` and personally, I would change the param names for some of them so it becomes much clearer what they stand for.

The code below uses [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7) to feed the parameters to the New-ADUser cmdlet. This is a nice readable and maintainable way of calling on cmdlets with lots of properties.

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=0)]
    [string]$GivenName,    # =givenName

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
    [string]$SurName,      # =SurName

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2)]
    [string]$AccountName,  # =SamAccountName

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=3)]
    [string]$Description,  # =title

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=4)]
    [string]$OU,           #= distinguishedName of the OU

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=5)]
    [string]$SamAccManager #= AdminDisplayName
)

# create a hashtable for the New-ADUser parameters
$userParams = @{
    Name              = "$GivenName $SurName"
    DisplayName       = "$GivenName $SurName"
    Description       = $Description
    GivenName         = $GivenName
    Surname           = $SurName
    SamAccountName    = $AccountName
    UserPrincipalName = "$AccountName@yourdomain.com"
    Path              = $OU
    # add the AdminDisplayName attribute as hashtable
    OtherAttributes   = @{AdminDisplayName = $SamAccManager}
}

# create the user by splatting the parameters
New-ADUser @userParams
```

Of course, you can also set the AdminDisplayName property after creating the user by using

```
Set-ADuser -Identity $AccountName -Add @{AdminDisplayName = $SamAccManager}
```

Comment: basically when I create the user, I add that position parameter of $SamAccManager, that will be the samaccountname of the user that requested the generic user, so I can know exactly how many they have and who are those users managed by, and I chose the attribute adminDisplayName so in the adminDisplayName, there will be a string that will represent the user that made the request

Comment: @CălimanuLoredan Sure, but the question was how to add that (requestor) user in the `AdminDisplayName` attribute of the user and I think I have answered that, no?

Comment: Yes, you did, I will see how to modify my script, as I pasted just bits and pieces of the entire script due to some security reasons and other stuff that imply the company. after that I will mark it as a solution if it fits the need. if not I will come back and explain any roadblocks. thanks a lot.

Comment: As we are on the same script, how could I implement a parameter with input yes OR no, so I can chose if some users will have password never expire or not. I want the script to take a paramenter as an input with YES --> password never expire , NO --> default with password expire.

Comment: @CălimanuLoredan You could implement that as [1] a switch parameter: `[switch]$PasswordNeverExpires` and add that to the $userParams hashtable `PasswordNeverExpires= [bool]$PasswordNeverExpires`. Then if this parameter to the script is not given, it will default to $false. [2] Or you can do an optional parameter `[ValidateSet('Yes','No')];[string]$PasswordNeverExpires = 'No'` and inside the $userParams set it like this: `PasswordNeverExpires= ($PasswordNeverExpires -eq 'Yes')`

Comment: I have added a new parameter as above with the admin display name and after that 
if ($PasswordNeverExpire -like "Y*") {Set-ADUser -Identity $user -PasswordNeverExpires $true }

Comment: @CălimanuLoredan Yes, setting it after creating the new user that work too.